# Creating a data context with a data option in iron-router not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

Whilst using iron router 1.011 with Meteor I created a router which returns a Mongo db cursor to a collection subset using a route parameter; see below:

```
Router.route('/categories/:slug', function() {
    this.render('CategoryShow', {
        data: {
            category_products: Products.find({
                category: this.params.slug
            })
        }
    })
});
```

This works fine, however I didn’t see this as particularly elegant and decide to pass the options as an object as per the documents; see below.

```
Router.route('/categories/:slug', {
  data: function() {
     templateData = {
         category_products: Products.find({
            category: this.params.slug
        })
     }
     return templateData;
 },
     name: 'category.show'
});
```

This does not return any `data` to the template but I notice that this pattern seem to work find when using `findOne()` instead of `find()`. Note that the template is declared as:

```
<Template name="CategoryShow">
     // bla bla
</Template>
```

Please advise

Comment: you need to return an array so something like this might work: `return [{data: Producnt.findOne...}]` if I'm not wrong don't use iron router anymore

Comment: Ok I'll try it but I'm not using findOne, I'm using find( ) to return a cursor to the whole collection. Which router are you using? Why did you switch?